# Hover effect transition on a split button

Tags: html, css, hover, css-transitions

I have a button with icon and I want on hover to appear one background color for the text part and another for the icon. The problem is that is seems that the hover transition is doubled and the backgrounds show one by one instead at the same time. Any ideas how to solve this?

Here's a codepen link to what Im trying to do: https://codepen.io/christmastrex/pen/RwGoeZq

Here's my html `<a class="btn btn--transparent" href="#bio-ufoma">Read Bio <i class="fal fa-arrow-right btn--transparent--arrow"></i></a>`

Comment: you need to add `transition` css in `a:after` also `transition: all .3s ease-in-out;`

Comment: @MinalChauhan thank you! That solves it :)